# Alternating tensor definition

Tags: permutations, tensor-products, tensors

I am working through a book ([Random Fields and Geometry](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387481128)) which contains the following definitions.

> A covariant tensor $\gamma$ of order $k$ (a $(k,0)$-tensor) is said to be *alternating* if
>
> $$\gamma(v_{\sigma(1)},...v_{\sigma(k)})=\epsilon_{\sigma}\gamma(v_{1},...v_{k}) \text{ for all } \sigma\in S(k)$$
>
> where $S(k)$ is the symmetric group of permutations of $k$ letters and $\epsilon_\sigma$ is the sign of the permutation $\sigma$.

I think I understand this so far. Please could someone confirm my understanding up until this point? As I understand it, $\epsilon_\sigma$ is like the [Levi-Civata symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) and an alternating tensor is a tensor which satisfies the condition that if we permute the basis vectors using an odd permutation the sign of the vector components are flipped. Is this correct so far? I am hesitant as the book never defines the $v_i$ notation used above and I am unsure if this represents basis vectors or vector components. Any clarity would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbols $v_i$ and $v_{\sigma(i)}$ represent vectors, so if you permute the input vectors {$v_i$} given to the tensor $\gamma$ then you get the same result for the unpermuted vectors multiplied by the ${\rm sgn}(\sigma)$ (or $\epsilon_\sigma$). The latter gives $+1$ or $-1$ depending on the parity of the permutation used on the vectors

Comment: Oh! I see! Yes that makes a lot more sense than what I was thinking! Thank you!